# Under what (mathematical) condition can a quantum interaction potential be ignored?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interactions, approximations

Suppose there are two quantum systems. Suppose that they are subject to an interaction potential which has a limited spatial range, as in, it is *exactly zero* outside of a certain spatial range. Thus if the systems are spatially close enough they interact, otherwise they do not. What is the condition in terms of the quantum states of the systems and the potential which guarantees the systems are not interacting?

In more precise language. Consider two quantum systems $S_1$ and $S_2$. Suppose their Hamiltonian can be expressed as a sum of a free and an interaction Hamiltonian: $H= H_0+V$. Suppose that the interaction has a limited spatial range, i.e. when the systems are far away enough it is *exactly zero*. What is the condition in terms of the quantum state of the systems $|\psi_1, \psi_2 (t) \rangle $, $V$ (and $H_0$, if needed) such that if the condition is met, the evolution of $|\psi_1, \psi_2 (t) \rangle $ ignores the interaction potential $V$?

Having a clear example in mind could be helpful. Suppose the two quantum systems are two electrons with a quantum state $|\psi_1, \psi_2 (t) \rangle = \psi (\textbf{r}_1, \textbf{r}_2; t)$ interacting under a potential just like the coloumb potential, but with a finite range $L$:

$$H=\frac{|\textbf{p}_1|^2}{2m_e} +\frac{|\textbf{p}_2|^2}{2m_e}+\frac{Ke^2}{|\textbf{r}_1-\textbf{r}_2|}\theta(L-|\textbf{r}_1-\textbf{r}_2|)$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the heavyside function. However, note this is just an example: I am interested in a condition in terms of a general $V$ and $|\psi_1, \psi_2 (t)\rangle$.

I am interested in both conditions which guarantees that $V$ can be ignored exactly, and also conditions which guarantee that $V$ can be neglected *only approximately*.

Note that I am not interested in a condition which ensures that the quantum systems will never interact. Rather, the condition I am interested in is of the following kind: if the quantum state of $S_1 \cup S_2$ at a time $t$ satisfy the condition (C), then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not interacting ***at time $t$***.

Comment: What does short ranged mean here? Is $V$ zero outside some range or does it decay with distance and if so how fast? What do we know about the form of $H_0$?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment. I have edited the question to clarify that I intend the potential to be exactly zero. Regarding the second part of your comment, I am looking for a condition which does not rely on the form of $H_0$. Note that the condition does not need to ensure that the systems will not interact in the future, but only that they are not interacting at the time.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "two quantum systems"? Do you mean two interacting electrons? or two $N$-electron states coming from the same Hamiltonian with that form? By "the quantum state of the systems" $|\psi_{1},\psi_{2}\rangle$ do you mean the ground-state of $H$ or something else entirely?

Comment: To clarify the question I added an example. The quantum systems may be any system that one can treat with quantum mechanics, for example, two electrons. The quantum state of the systems need not be the ground state: just their quantum state at a certain time. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Is the condition here not obviously just that the support of the position wavefunctions of the $\psi_i$ is disjoint from the support of the potential at all times? I'm not really sure what physical use case you have in mind here - which interactions are ever zero outside a finite interval?

Comment: @ACuriousMind is this what you mean: $V|\psi_1, \psi_2 (t) \rangle$ =0 ? That’s also what I was thinking, but asking for some external opinion. Also, if $V|\psi_1, \psi_2 (t)\rangle= \lambda |\psi_1, \psi_2 (t)\rangle$ the interaction only adds a phase, so it seems to me it leaves probabilities invariant. But I’m asking for other opinions on it. I am not sure if there are any interactions, but I guess if the condition is approximately met, the interaction potential can be neglected for all practical purposes?

Comment: I don't think it is quite that simple. We can imagine that we produce the interacting propagator $U$; in principle we can do this for your two-electron Hamiltonian because the problem of the relative coordinate $\vert \textbf{r}_{1}-\textbf{r}_{2}\vert$ is essentially one-particle: $\hat{p}^{2}_{u}/2 + v(u)$. Any initial wave-function you propagate will necessarily contain information about the cusp $u=0$. It is not clear whether, after enough time, the propagated wave-function will ever be "non-interacting", i.e. an anti-symmetrized product of single-electron functions because of this.

Comment: Since this question might seem too general to answer, I’ve asked a similar question with a specific example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781346/why-can-we-ignore-other-charged-particles-when-dealing-with-the-hydrogen-atom
However, I would still like to leave this open, in the hope that someone might be able to answer it.