# Why can we ignore other charged particles when dealing with the Hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, interactions, approximations, hydrogen

Introductory treatments of the Hydrogen atom use the following Hamiltonian:

$$H=\frac{|\textbf{p}_p|^2}{2m_p} +\frac{|\textbf{p}_e|^2}{2m_e}-\frac{Ke^2}{|\textbf{r}_p-\textbf{r}_e|}$$

However, given that the Coloumb interaction has infinte range (though it decays, it never goes exactly to zero), then the *actual* Hamiltonian of the Hydrogen atom should include interaction terms with all other charged particles in the universe. For simplicity, suppose there is only one other electron in the universe. Then, the Hamiltonian should be as follows:

$$H=\frac{|\textbf{p}_p|^2}{2m_p} +\frac{|\textbf{p}_{e1}|^2}{2m_e}+ \frac{|\textbf{p}_{e2}|^2}{2m_e}-\frac{Ke^2}{|\textbf{r}_p-\textbf{r}_{e1}|}- \frac{Ke^2}{|\textbf{r}_p-\textbf{r}_{e2}|} + \frac{Ke^2}{|\textbf{r}_{e1}-\textbf{r}_{e2}|} $$

Surely, if the other electron is far away enough from the Hydrogen atom we will be able to neglect the latter two potential terms for all practical purposes. What is our mathematical justification to do so?

Comment: The justification is that there is no evidence that we need to throw in interactions with all the other particles in the universe. And we know that atom-atom interactions are fairly short ranged (see Chemistry).

Comment: I mean, you said it in your question. The unless the other charges are very close by other terms are much, much smaller. That is mathematical justification enough

Comment: Since we expect the wave function to be (effectively) non zero only in a very small region around the nucleus of the hydrogen atom, it follows that the interaction terms from far away charges contribute (almost) nothing in any of the calculations we do (since if we apply $H$ to such a wave function, the contribution of the far away charge term is essentially $0$).

Comment: We are free to model a hydrogen atom as an electron and a proton alone in vacuum. This is an approximation to the real world, but all models are approximations. Regarding real-world screening effects, you may want to check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric-field_screening#Quantum-mechanical_approach

Comment: We don’t ignore these effects when considering the hydrogen molecule $H_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest explanation I can come up with is that at long distances (compared to the size of the hydrogen atom) the negative charge of the electron cancels the positive charge of the proton and at those long distances the hydrogen atom is electrically neutral, meaning it does not interact electrostatically with the rest of the universe.

This charge cancellation effect fails at very short distances (scale length ~ atom diameter) because the electron and proton are not sitting exactly on top of each other all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to address your question, my answer reverses the point of view of @Nielsnielsen 's answer. However, the physics behind it is the same.

The original question was about the need to include interactions with other charges when discussing the behavior of *the proton and the electron of a hydrogen atom*. A third electron was added, just an example of an external charge modifying the electron-ion Hamiltonian. Now, the introduction of a single charge does not account for the real situation of a typical hydrogen atom quite far from *many*  other charges. So, the key point is that there are many more charges around than a single extra-electron. Moreover, these other charges screen themselves in a quite efficient way (local neutrality).

By the way, this mechanism of screening is the same that allows the stability of the matter under normal conditions. The proof that the thermodynamic limit exists for matter made by positive and negative charges heavily depends on the screening properties of a system of electrons an nuclei.

Comment: Thank you Giorgio for the very helpful reply. Do you have a reference (book or paper) where I could learn something about the screening properties of a system of electrons and nuclei?